# MongoDB, Django 2.2 и DjOngo

Tags: python-3.x, django, mongodb

Пытаюсь подключиться к MongoDB с помощью Django и DjOngo.

Файл settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
    }
}
```

Файл urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from mainapp.views import Index

urlpatterns = [
    path('mainapp/', Index.as_view()),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Файл views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .models import Part, Books

class Index(TemplateView):
    template_name = "base.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['books_list'] = Books.objects.all()
        context['len'] = len(Books.objects.all())
        return context
```

Файл models.py:

```
from djongo import models

class Part(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)

class Books(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=18)
    part_id = models.ForeignKey(Part, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

В файле base.html просто `{{ len }}` и

```
{% for li in books_list%}
<a href="">{{ li.name }}</a>
```

Создал и выполнил миграции - успешно.
Но при попытке вывести данные на страницу ничего не выводит.
Проверил длину результата - 0.
В чем здесь дело?

Comment: Ну а данные-то в базе вообще есть? Может, их и в самом деле ровно ноль? Что нужно вывести-то?

Comment: Да, в коллекции Part - 2 документа, а в Books - 10

Comment: Посмотрите, заходит ли в эту функцию вообще. Если да - то какие там значения. Если нет - то показывайте urls.

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 заходит, ведь 0 всё же выводится

Comment: добавил файл urls.py